# Show all records on a RIGHT JOIN query with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I inherited the following table

**DEALS**

```
id, office_id, sale_date.
```

There are some 13 000 records with around 60 different office_id's. I need a query to count the number of transactions (records), grouping each office_id by YEAR-QUARTER.

When I use this

```
SELECT  office_id, concat(YEAR(sale_date), "-", quarter(sale_date)) as period, count(id) AS transactions 
FROM `deals` 
GROUP BY office_id, period
```

I get

```
office_id, sale_date, transactions
66, 2020-4, 5
45, 2020-4, 9
23, 2020-4, 7
67, 2020-3, 9
43, 2020-3, 4
66, 2020-3, 3
45, 2020-3, 8
23, 2020-3, 2
66, 2020-2, 6
45, 2020-2, 5
```

Want I want to get is all office_id's for all periods as below even if there are no records.

```
office_id, sale_date, transactions
67, 2020-4, NULl
43, 2020-4, NULL
66, 2020-4, 5
45, 2020-4, 9
23, 2020-4, 7
67, 2020-3, 9
43, 2020-3, 4
66, 2020-3, 3
45, 2020-3, 8
23, 2020-3, 2
67, 2020-2, NULL
43, 2020-2, NULL
66, 2020-2, 6
45, 2020-2, 5
23, 2020-2, NULL
```

I hope this makes sense. Any help will be appreciated, I am a complete noob.

Comment: what determines what are "all periods"?  some specific range of quarters?  all offices found in some other table?

Comment: @ysth The periods are determined by sale_date. It is the 4 quarters of the year. Sorry I see I left out office_id in the GROUP BY. I edited the original question

Comment: let me try asking a different way:  if there are no records at all in deals, would you want no rows?  or is there some set of periods you want reported?  and same question with office_id

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

***MySQL 8***

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT MIN(sale_date) AS n FROM deals
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + INTERVAL 1 QUARTER 
  FROM cte
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM n) < (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM MAX(sale_date)) FROM deals)
)
SELECT 
   o.office_id,
    concat(YEAR(n), "-", quarter(n)) as period,
   COUNT(d.id) AS transactions
FROM cte
JOIN offices o
LEFT JOIN deals d ON d.office_id = o.office_id AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM d.sale_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH From n)
GROUP BY o.office_id, period
ORDER BY o.office_id, period;
```

- First cte is used to generate `quarter` list based on `min` and `max` sale date from `deals` table.
- Then `cross joined` with office table to make sure we do've records for each office and each quarter.
- Now left joined with deals table to find how many transactions per `office` and `quarter`.

There might be some optimized way but it will give you the results.

Comment: Sorry, I see I left out the Group By office_id in my question but I did have it in my query. What I want is for the 4 quarters of every year to be show in the results for each of the office_id's that exist in the table even if there are no records for a partiular office_id  in the a particular quarter (period). For example, office_id 43 only has records that falls in the period 1July 2020 to 30 Sep 2020 (the 3rd quarter of 2020). I want the other periods to show in the results for office_id 43 with a NULL value. 
43 2020-1 NULL, 
43 2020-2 NULL, 
43 2020-3 4, 
43 2020-4 NULL

Comment: This cannot provide the presence in output for the combinations `(office_id, period)` which are absent in source data.

Comment: @Akina, question has been modified after the answer. Will update accordingly. Hope a comment before downvote is good to let answerer know, that he can improve. Bcz everybody doesn't come back and correct their voting even if answer has been updated.

Comment: @AllanBateman, there are two options two make sure you get the proper answer. First if you have a table with `offices` that would be great otherwise we can find `distinct office_id` from same table. Second if you want all quarters whether there is data present or not in that situation what about a period when there is no data from any office. Do you want to generate it or skip it. Based on your response will update the answer.

Comment: @Jitendra Thank you. Yes, I do have a table with offices. That where the table id comes from when the deals table is populated. It has the Office_id and office_name. Second question, yes I want to generate it even if there is no data for any office.

Comment: *question has been modified after the answer.* I have not seen the initial question text. I operate only with question's and answer's current states. And they do not match - this is a reason of downvote. If you want the downvote to be removed (or even to receive an upvote) you must sync current question state and your answer text.

Comment: Are you sure in `<=` used in CTE's WHERE in recursive part? It must give excess row.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I think it would add extra one. updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You must gather the offices list in separate subquery, do the same with periods, then outer join source table to their combination.

The subqueries provides you any possible pair `(office, period)`, even when such pair is absent in the data. But separate values for `office` and `period` must present in a table.

```sql
SELECT offices.office_id, periods.period, COUNT(deals.id) transactions
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT office_id FROM deals) offices
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(sale_date), "-", QUARTER(sale_date)) period FROM deals) periods
LEFT JOIN deals ON deals.office_id = offices.office_id 
               AND CONCAT(YEAR(deals.sale_date), "-", QUARTER(deals.sale_date)) = periods.period
GROUP BY offices.office_id, periods.period
```

If your MySQL version is 8+ then convert subqueries to CTEs.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=adfb35b08626ec6f3c5f891cae248d7c) which demonstrates the technique.

If there is no any row for some `office` and/or `period` value which must be included then some external rowsource which provides such data presence in source data array must exist. For example, this can be a table of offices or CTE which generates full periods list based on the least and greatest sales dates over whole table.

Comment: what about a missing quarter(for which no data for any office)?

Comment: @JitendraYadav If so then you must either have a table with complete quarters list in interest or generate such list in recursive CTE (or by another way).

Comment: @JitendraYadav The remark about such situation added.

Comment: I can add a table for the period which could hold the 4 quarters for every year as the "period" In other words;

id  period

1 2020-4

2 2020-3

3 2020-2

4 2020-1

5 2019-4

6 2019-3

7 2019-2

8 2019-1

and so on. Would that work? (Sorry, I don't know how to show this in table format in this chat)

Comment: @AllanBateman Of course... but I do not see the reason, it is more simple and more dynamic to specify starting and finishing date and generate the quarters list in a query (especially if your MySQL is 8+).